# How do SSHDs handle VHD files larger than its cache?

Tags: ssd, vhd

My understanding of the SSHD drive is that it will store the most frequently accessed files in its SSD cache. I am curious how it would handle larger files such as a VHDX that would exceed its cache size. Would it store part of that file in it's cache? Or would it just not consider that file and store something like the OS files there?

Comment: The same way HDDs with caches handle it.

Comment: I dont know about that as well. Will it store part of that file in its cache or not?

Comment: Even if the file was smaller then the cache on the HDD/SSD it wouldn't permanently be stored in the cache.  You should research what the cache is used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drive doesn’t know about files at all. Instead, it knows about [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(data_storage)). They are what’s cached and also the unit whose usage is analyzed.

As such, only the most used parts of a large file would be cached. If all parts of the file were equally used, it would select a (seemingly) random amount of parts to cache.

Comment: Indeed. As far as a hard drive (or SSD, or SSHD, or USB key, etc.) is concerned there isn't really any such thing as a file, or even a partition or a boot block. There are only blocks. There's nothing you can do at the command interface to a hard drive but read or write blocks, specified by their logical block address (LBA). The file system driver in the OS is the highest level in the storage stack where any notion of "files" exists. It uses some of the blocks to store things it calls directories, a master file table, etc. But to the storage device they're all just blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am curious because I have been considering an SSHD for a hyper v server. Seagate makes a SSHD that is super cheap but they are advertised as being for desktop/gaming. Would you advise against these for a hyper v server in a RAID 1 even though they are ultimately consumer grade hard drives?

Comment: Daniel - any chance you can cite a reference for your answer? (blocks vs. file caching). Thanks friend!